# UAC never asks for admin password, denies access on admin-related tasks, on client computer. How to fix UAC?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, active-directory, uac

I have a client computer, Windows 7 64 bit, connected to our network. The user who signs on is not an admin (according to our active directory). It's having credential issues which I'm trying to fix according to [this particular post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e1ef04fa-6aea-47fe-9392-45929239bd68/securitykerberos-event-id-14-credential-manager-causes-system-to-login-to-network-with-invalid?forum=w7itprosecurity), however each time I attempt to elevate the command prompt to admin, it never asks for a password nor does it actually elevate the cmd to admin.

I have attempted to turn off/on UAC via command prompt and receive an access denied.

I have also attempted to fix it the old fashioned way by going into the account settings, but when I click on the "Change User Account Control settings" link, it does absolutely nothing.

This admin problem is with everything including installing new printers and programs and modifying settings. It only happens to this one particular account on this computer. Is there a way to fix this weird admin-less UAC issue without having to completely scrap the local account and rebuild it locally?

My AD server is 2012 R2, though it honestly had the same issues with our 2003 server, so I'm pretty sure this is a local issue.

Comment: Does this problem follow the user to other devices?

Comment: If it truly is that single user on that single machine, and the problem does not follow the user, just image the machine again.  I am going to guess you have spent more time trying to figure out the reason, the user has this problem, then it would take to actually just do that.

Comment: You wouldn't exactly be wrong about the time so far. It seems to be primarily a local issue. I was hoping to be able to fix it without having to scrub and rebuild the account. If that is possible at this point.

Comment: Sure;  If the problem follows the user, to other machines, that tells us a great deal.

Comment: The _original_ problem follows the user. The account claims to be locked on any other computer and will not permit the user to log on. This problem started on our old 2003 server and thought it was a local thing since it followed to the new 2012 server. I thought fixing the UAC issue would fix a potential credential issue. Even stranger, the AD does not say the account is locked. I am honestly at a loss right now.